# Phantom maps in chromatic homotopy theory

Tags: at.algebraic-topology

It is well-known that there are no non-trivial phantom maps in rational homotopy theory.

Is this also true in Chromatic homotopy theory?

Precisely, let $T(n)$ be the telescope on a $v_n$-self map of a type $n$ spectrum.

Are there non-trivial phantom maps in $T(n)$-local spectra, $K(n)$-local spectra?

Comment: This paper appears to have lots of relevant info: https://jdc.math.uwo.ca/papers/all-or-nothing.pdf

Comment: @Eric Peterson: Thanks a lot! Looks like I was looking for.